# Funcion para omitir datos durante un array

Tags: php, array, mysqli

Tengo el siguiente codigo en el que desde una fecha X hasta una fecha X obtengo los dias transcurrido de la semana, fecha, mes y año

```
<?php
   $fecha1 = "2018-12-29";
   $fecha2 = "2019-01-12";

   for($i=$fecha1;$i<=$fecha2;$i = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($i ."+ 1 days")))
   {
       echo dia_semana($i). "<br />";
   }


   function dia_semana($fecha)
   {
       $dia = date("d", strtotime($fecha));

       $dias = array('', 'LUNES', 'MARTES', 'MIERCOLES', 'JUEVES', 'VIERNES', 'SÁBADO', 'DOMINGO');
       $dia_semana = $dias[date('N', strtotime($fecha))];
       $dia_semana .=" ".$fecha;
       return $dia_semana;
   }
?>
```

Esto me devuelve

```
SÁBADO 2018-12-29
DOMINGO 2018-12-30 etc..
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que durante el array me cumpla la función de omitir unos ciertos datos, por ejemplo si incluye estos datos los descarta por completo: `$funcin_omite = "Sabado , Domingo`  al igual que fechas como mes y dia: `01-02 , etc.."`

No encuentro como hacer esto posible, alguna solución?

La idea principal es :

1)Obtener las fechas por un input date desde y hasta, por alli todo bien.

2)Luego imprime los resultado como lo mencione arriba

Pero antes de eso yo quiero que si existe un dato parecido a la funcione omite, esto descarta toda la fila que existe con ese dato

Answer (score 1):

Lo logre añadiendole al for lo siguiente:

```
$string = dia_semana($i). "<br />";
        $rows = explode("\n",$string);
//Aqui exluyo con | las palabras que debe omitir
$unwanted = "SABADO|DOMINGO|-01-09";
$cleanArray= preg_grep("/$unwanted/i",$rows,PREG_GREP_INVERT);
$cleanString=implode("\n",$cleanArray);
//Me muestra las fechas sin los datos que se exluyeron
echo $cleanString;
```